# Ruby on rails web services with POST request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, http-post

I've just started learning Ruby on rails and I am wondering how to do something that I know how to easily do in PHP.
I want to create some basic web services that can be called with POST parameters and send a JSON as a response. I don't know at all how to start with that using Ruby on rails.

I am sure there are some best practice to do that kind of things, so if you guys could advise me anything, it would be great!

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the POST parameters, you just look into the params hash in your controller, which will have any and all parameters for the request, whether they're coming as POST params, GET params, or as part of the route (e.g. /users/:id/new => params[:id] in the controller)

To return json from the request, you'd just make a render call like this:

```
render :json => @model
```

Beyond that, your question is a bit broad for the scope of an answer on SO.  I recommend reading [Agile Web Development with Rails](http://pragprog.com/titles/rails4/agile-web-development-with-rails) as a starting point to learn Rails development.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a good fit for Sinatra. Check out http://www.sinatrarb.com/

Answer (score 0):

The great thing about rails is that it is based on the principal of REST.

Whenever you create a RESTful resource, you are in fact creating a web service at the same time.

For example. Say you create a resource using a scaffold generator.

```
rails g scaffold Feed title:string content:string
```

This will not only create all the view logic in HTML, but also in xml.

Further to your first comment:

If you look in the controller, within the `respond_to` block you can specify the return type. So you want to hit the xml version of `new` and return the json version of `create`.

To render your treated parameters to json, put them in a hash:

```
js = {:my => {:json => 'hash'}}
render :json => js
```

Comment: Yes I've understood that, but I don't know how to do to fetch the parameters of a POST request on one of my pages, do a treatment on them and depending on that treatment, return a JSON string

Comment: I'd say you need to look into `respond_to`, I haven't used web services that much but I've certainly returned json before.

Comment: but how to customize the json string ?

Comment: you'd do that in the controller method, ruby hashes reflect json nicely, so if you format all of your data into a hash or series of nested hashes and return that, it will convert to json